# Tic-Tac-Toe in python 3.5.2

Tags: python, beginner, game, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a fun, easy game of tic-tac-toe, but my code editor is very limiting. If anyone has a suggestion to make this better, or a good, free code editor, I would love to know.

By running this code, you play a very simple game of tic-tac-toe, but it doesn't show any pictures. You need to remember all the moves by yourself

```
def print_board(board):

    i= float(input("""The board look like this: \n
                     _1_|_2_|_3_
                     _4_|_5_|_6_
                      7 | 8 | 9  """))

    for i in range(3):
        print " ",
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i*3+j] == 1:
                print 'X',
            elif board[i*3+j] == 0:
                print 'O',  
            elif board[i*3+j] != -1:
                print board[i*3+j]-1,
            else:
                print ' ',

            if j != 2:
                print " | ",
        print

        if i != 2:
            print "-----------------"
        else: 
            print 

def print_instruction():
    print "Please use the following cell numbers to make your move"
    print_board([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])


def get_input(turn):

    valid = False
    while not valid:
        try:
            user = raw_input("Where would you like to place " + turn + " (1-9)? ")
            user = int(user)
            if user >= 1 and user <= 9:
                return user-1
            else:
                print "That is not a valid move! Please try again.\n"
                print_instruction()
        except Exception as e:
            print user + " is not a valid move! Please try again.\n"

def check_win(board):
    win_cond = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(3,5,7))
    for each in win_cond:
        try:
            if board[each[0]-1] == board[each[1]-1] and board[each[1]-1] == board[each[2]-1]:
                return board[each[0]-1]
        except:
            pass
    return -1

def quit_game(board,msg):
    print_board(board)
    print msg
    quit()

def main():

    # setup game
    # alternate turns
    # check if win or end
    # quit and show the board

    print_instruction()

    board = []
    for i in range(9):
        board.append(-1)

    win = False
    move = 0
    while not win:

        # print board
        print_board(board)
        print "Turn number " + str(move+1)
        if move % 2 == 0:
            turn = 'X'
        else:
            turn = 'O'

        # get user input
        user = get_input(turn)
        while board[user] != -1:
            print "Invalid move! Cell already taken. Please try again.\n"
            user = get_input(turn)
        board[user] = 1 if turn == 'X' else 0

        # advance move and check for end game
        move += 1
        if move > 4:
            winner = check_win(board)
            if winner != -1:
                out = "The winner is " 
                out += "X" if winner == 1 else "O" 
                out += " :)"
                quit_game(board,out)
            elif move == 9:
                quit_game(board,"No winner :(")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This sounds mostly like you want a new IDE and want our opinions, rather than you wanting a full review of your code.  (Have you considered PyCharm for your IDE, though?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Be wary of inline multi-line strings as they will preserve your indentation.

   ```
   input("""The board look like this: \n
           _1_|_2_|_3_
           _4_|_5_|_6_
            7 | 8 | 9  """)
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   The board look like this:

                        _1_|_2_|_3_
                        _4_|_5_|_6_
                         7 | 8 | 9
   ```
2. the result of your input is saved to `i` but `i` is overwritten by the for loop immediately afterwards. Assuming that you are just waiting for the user to hit enter, there is no need to call `float()` or assign the value of the input.
3. one way to simplify printing your board by using a format:

   ```
   char_values = {-1: " ", 0: "O", 1: "X"}
   """
   %s | %s | %s
   %s | %s | %s
   %s | %s | %s
   """ % tuple(char_values[square] for square in board)
   ```
4. In `get_input` you are catching all Exceptions when you really just want to catch `ValueError`. This is especially a problem in python where `NameError`s, `KeyboardInterrupt`s and `EOFError`s are catchable.

   ```
   try:
       ...
       user = int(userer)
       ...
   except Exception as e:
       print user + " is not a valid move! Please try again.\n"
   ```

   will print `user + " is not a valid move! Please try again.\n"`
5. The same thing is being done in `check_win()`, but I can't figure out the when an exception would even occur that you would want to catch. `board` should always be the same length.
6. ```
   board = []
   for i in range(9):
       board.append(-1)
   ```

   can be written simply as

   ```
   board = [-1] * 9
   # or
   board = [-1 for _ in range(9)]
   ```
7. Since `quit_game()` already exits, why not have a for loop over the moves, because there are at most 9, and `win` isn't even used.